# Enabling the OpenGL Core Profile in pyglet on OS X

Tags: python, macos, opengl, pyglet

I'm trying to get a minimal OpenGL shader working in pyglet but getting the following error when it compiles:

```
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '420' is not supported
```

It seems like this might be due to pyglet using the legacy OpenGL profile as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931528/shader-cant-be-compiled) but if that is the case how can I get pyglet to use a diffrent profile? I can't find it documented anywhere and feel like I must be missing something obvious.

The following code reproduces the problem (adapted from [this example](https://swiftcoder.wordpress.com/2008/12/19/simple-glsl-wrapper-for-pyglet/)):

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.gl as gl
import ctypes

window = pyglet.window.Window()
handle = gl.glCreateProgram()
shader = gl.glCreateShader(gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

source = """
#version 420

in vec3 vertex_position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
}
"""

src = ctypes.c_char_p(source)
gl.glShaderSource(shader, 1,
    ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(src),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))), None)
gl.glCompileShader(shader)

# Retrieve compilation status
status = ctypes.c_int(0)
gl.glGetShaderiv(shader, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, ctypes.byref(status))
# If compilation failed, print the log
if not status:
    gl.glGetShaderiv(shader, gl.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, ctypes.byref(status))
    buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(status.value)
    gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, status, None, buffer)
    print buffer.value

pyglet.app.run()
```

- Hardware: MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012) Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB
- OSX: 10.10.1
- Python: 2.7.6
- pyglet: 1.2.4

Comment: OSX does not support GL 4.2. It will support version 2.1 as legacy backward compatibility and 3.2 to 4.1 in core profile. So you might already have a core profile. `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` will tell you what you got.

Comment: Thanks @derhass it is useful to know 4.2 would never have worked! I tried using `#version 320` instead and got a similar error. Trying glGetString(GL_VERSION) gives me 2.1 INTEL-10.0.86 so it seems like pyglet is using the legacy profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an open bug, there is an unresolved issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/pyglet/issues/detail?id=532) in the old Google code repo, and I've filed a new bug [here](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/issues/65/cant-create-a-30-opengl-context-on-osx).

So I guess currently (as of pyglet 1.2.4) it's not possible to get a >3.0 OpenGL context.