# OpenGL - Why am i getting this error? COMPILATION_FAILED version '330' is not supported

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl, glfw

I'm using Xcode (Version 12.0.1) on macOS 10.15.7.

I brew installed the latest versions of glew, glfw, glm with Homebrew, and tried running this simple code snippet, my OpenGL version seems to be incompatible with the shaders used.

I do not want to change the code, any way to downgrade the shaders? (Could it be done with Homebrew as well?)

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>


//#define GLEW_STATIC 1   // This allows linking with Static Library on Windows, without DLL
#include <GL/glew.h>    // Include GLEW - OpenGL Extension Wrangler

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // GLFW provides a cross-platform interface for creating a graphical context,
                        // initializing OpenGL and binding inputs

#include <glm/glm.hpp>  // GLM is an optimized math library with syntax to similar to OpenGL Shading Language


const char* getVertexShaderSource()
{
    // Insert Shaders here ...
     // For now, you use a string for your shader code, in the assignment, shaders will be stored in .glsl files

     return
                 "#version 330 core\n"
                 "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;"
                 "layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;"
                 "out vec3 vertexColor;"
                 "void main()"
                 "{"
                 "   vertexColor = aColor;"
                 "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);"
                 "}";

}


const char* getFragmentShaderSource()
{
    return
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "in vec3 vertexColor;"
    "out vec4 FragColor;"
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "   FragColor = vec4(vertexColor.r, vertexColor.g, vertexColor.b, 1.0f);"
    "}";
}


int compileAndLinkShaders()
{
    // compile and link shader program
       // return shader program id
       // ------------------------------------


       // vertex shader
       int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
       const char* vertexShaderSource = getVertexShaderSource();
       glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
       glCompileShader(vertexShader);
       
       // check for shader compile errors
       int success;
       char infoLog[512];
       glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
       if (!success)
       {
           glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
           std::cerr << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
       }
       
       // fragment shader
       int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
       const char* fragmentShaderSource = getFragmentShaderSource();
       glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
       glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
       
       // check for shader compile errors
       glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
       if (!success)
       {
           glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
           std::cerr << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
       }
       
       // link shaders
       int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
       glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
       glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
       glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
       
       // check for linking errors
       glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
       if (!success) {
           glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
           std::cerr << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
       }
       
       glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
       glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
       
       return shaderProgram;

    //return -1;
}

int createVertexArrayObject()
{
    // A vertex is a point on a polygon, it contains positions and other data (eg: colors)
       glm::vec3 vertexArray[] = {
           glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f),  // top center position
           glm::vec3( 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f),  // top center color (red)
           glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f),  // bottom right
           glm::vec3( 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f),  // bottom right color (green)
           glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f),  // bottom left
           glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f),  // bottom left color (blue)
       };
       
       // Create a vertex array
       GLuint vertexArrayObject;
       glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
       glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
       
       
       // Upload Vertex Buffer to the GPU, keep a reference to it (vertexBufferObject)
       GLuint vertexBufferObject;
       glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
       glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
       glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexArray), vertexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

       glVertexAttribPointer(0,                   // attribute 0 matches aPos in Vertex Shader
                             3,                   // size
                             GL_FLOAT,            // type
                             GL_FALSE,            // normalized?
                             2*sizeof(glm::vec3), // stride - each vertex contain 2 vec3 (position, color)
                             (void*)0             // array buffer offset
                             );
       glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


       glVertexAttribPointer(1,                            // attribute 1 matches aColor in Vertex Shader
                             3,
                             GL_FLOAT,
                             GL_FALSE,
                             2*sizeof(glm::vec3),
                             (void*)sizeof(glm::vec3)      // color is offseted a vec3 (comes after position)
                             );
       glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

       glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // VAO already stored the state we just defined, safe to unbind buffer
       glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind to not modify the VAO
       
       return vertexArrayObject;
}


int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    // Initialize GLFW and OpenGL version
    glfwInit();

#if defined(PLATFORM_OSX)
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#else
    // On windows, we set OpenGL version to 2.1, to support more hardware
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
#endif

    // Create Window and rendering context using GLFW, resolution is 800x600
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Comp371 - Lab 01", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GLEW" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Black background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    
    
    // Compile and link shaders here ...
    int shaderProgram = compileAndLinkShaders();
    
    // Define and upload geometry to the GPU here ...
    int vao = createVertexArrayObject();
    
    
    // Entering Main Loop
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Each frame, reset color of each pixel to glClearColor
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        
        // TODO - draw rainbow triangle
        
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // 3 vertices, starting at index 0
        glBindVertexArray(0);


        // End frame
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
        // Detect inputs
        glfwPollEvents();
        
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }
    
    // Shutdown GLFW
    glfwTerminate();
    
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the error i'm getting

```
2021-01-22 21:23:23.336552-0500 OpenGLtest [27358:306573] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-01-22 21:23:23.361027-0500 OpenGLtest [27358:306750] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
2021-01-22 21:23:23.361368-0500 OpenGLtest [27358:306750] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '330' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 0:2: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error

ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '330' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 0:2: 'f' : syntax error: syntax error

ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED
ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled

Program ended with exit code: 9
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shader can't be compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931528/shader-cant-be-compiled)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to compile `#version 330` GLSL code on a GL 3.2 context.  Since [GL 3.2 only supports `#version`s up to `150`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language#Versions) that won't work.

Either re-write your GLSL to target `#version 150` or request a GL 3.3 context.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for some reason there's no way to install an older version of glew using homebrew commands, and after wasting an entire day on this, the error was solved by the following:

Xcode wasn't going into the #if, and was therefore executing the #else:

```
#if defined(PLATFORM_OSX)
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#else
    // On windows, we set OpenGL version to 2.1, to support more hardware
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
#endif
```

So I solved this by keeping this code only

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

I couldn't recreate this issue on VS code... Xcode was just being dumb?

Answer (score -2):

You're restricted to OpenGL 2.1 Context when calling OpenGL from a Unix System perspective on MacOSX. In order to get OpenGL3.2 in XCode use GLKit (GLK) Library functions to automatically retrieve a GL 3.2 context. These libraries are all now deprecated past OSX 10.14.